# Overriding 'next' in Streams

Tags: smalltalk

Here is basically what I want to do (I have implemented the Stream sub-class `WordStream`):

```
| aStream |
aStream := WordStream on: 'Test My Word Stream Class!'.
self assert: (aStream next) = 'Test'.
self assert: (aStream next) = 'My'.
self assert: (aStream next) = 'Word'.
self assert: (aStream next) = 'Stream'.
self assert: (aStream next) = 'Class'.
self assert: aStream atEnd
```

I've got everything stored correctly in my stream, but I can only figure out how to get the next word by doing:

```
next
    |tmpStream|
    tmpStream := ReadStream on: myStream contents.
    ^tmpStream nextDelimited: Character space.
```

This works for only the first word (obviously) - when I try to use my instance variable `myStream`, it just keeps returning ''.

i.e., I can't get this to work:

```
next
   ^myStream nextDelimited: Character space.
```

Could someone give me a hand?

---

### edit:

This is how I implemented `on:`

```
on: inString
    |tmpStream|
    myStream := ReadWriteStream on: String new.
    tmpStream := ReadStream on: inString.

    [ tmpStream atEnd ] whileFalse: [ myStream nextPutAll: (tmpStream nextDelimited: Character space); nextPut: $ ].
```

Comment: Are you subclassing `Stream` directly? Because `PositionableStream` ought to have `#nextDelimited:` implemented already.

Comment: Yeah, I'm inheriting directly from Stream. Should I consider a different approach you think? I didn't re-implement nextDelimited, so it appears to have been working thus far. I think I just don't quite understand exactly what it's doing maybe? Or maybe my order of operations is just whacky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PositionableStream` defines `#nextDelimited:` already, but that uses `#next`. One fairly horrible thing you could do is copy `PositionableStream >> #nextDelimited:`'s implementation, and replace the `self next` call with your own get-a-single-character method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  -  I'm not sure what you mean by `replace the self next call with your own get-a-single-character method.`

Comment: Take PositionalStream's implementation and copy it into your WordStream. Replace `self next` with `self nextChar` or something, and `#nextChar` returns the next character in the stream.

Comment: Hm, I'm actually wanting to return the next `word` in the stream

Comment: Yes, I know. You want your #next to be just like PositionalStream's #nextDelimited:, but you can't simply subclass PositionaStream and use it, because #nextDelimited uses #next. So copy the implementation, call it #next, and replace the #next call with something that returns the next character.